# How can blueimp communicate with a Java REST service, if possible

Tags: angularjs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

```
$scope.$on('fileuploadadd', function(e,data) {

$http({ 
       method: 'POST',

            }).success().error();
}
```

i know writing above code for single simple file upload, but with blueimp, 
can i manage progress with my rest service? also is above the right approach? 
i know there is a `data.submit` function, but i do not know how can it know to call which server side action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations to map request method on a restful function according to the Javax RS Api. So it depends of which Restful Java Api you use.

An example from [the oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html#gipxs):

```
package com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

// The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/helloworld"
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    // The Java method will process HTTP POST requests
    @POST
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media
    // type "text/plain"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

The Javascript :

```
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'http://yourSite/helloworld',
    type: 'POST',
    ...
```

Comment: my services are ready, problem is, how can i call my services in blueimp events

Comment: @mervellous I've edit my post, you just have to add your URL and the method type according to your REST controler.

Comment: Delete and get method don't seem to be supported by the plugin : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#type